# UITableView Multiple Selection

Tags: iphone, uitableview

How can I add a UITableView into my View-Based Application where the user will tap on more than one cell, and it will become selected, exactly like the Clock app's "New Alarm" setting named "Repeat" (Clock>Alarms> + >Repeat), and how can I get all of the selected cells in an array?

Comment: Psh.  I didn't see Apple's example on this.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

In your implementation of `-tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` you would set the table view cell's `accessoryType` property depending on its current value (so it would toggle on and off with multiple taps). For example:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)path {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:path];

    if (cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark) {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    } else {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    }
}
```

You could either maintain an array of selected states in addition to the cells' own accessory type state, or iterate over the cells in the table view querying for each one's state in order to read out the selected rows.

Comment: This won't work -- indexPath refers to the wrong cell when a cell is selected and you scroll.  As a result you will see multiple items checked.

Comment: As in the previous comment, this won't work as you will multiple items selected as you scroll.

Comment: -1 This solution has an issue, once you select certain rows and scroll you can see many check marks for those cell which you have not yet selected.

Comment: This solution have another issue when unchecking cell, you have to tap twice to make accessory type none, because when we select a cell it makes it accessory type checkmark and change its state to selected. So when you want to uncheck, it does not go to this method didSelectRowAtIndexPath but go to didDeselectRowAtIndexPath. So you have to implement this method also.

Comment: To solve reload issue, do this in cellForRowAtIndexPath:

      if(cell.isSelected)
    {
         cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    }else
    {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }

Comment: This will cause checkboxes to appear on table row items down stream because you are using the same cell.

Answer (score 153):

For multiple selection, add the line below in `viewDidLoad()`

```
tableView.allowsMultipleSelection = true
```

Configure each `cell` after dequeuing (or initializing) it in `tableView(_:cellForRowAt:)`

```
let selectedIndexPaths = tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows
let rowIsSelected = selectedIndexPaths != nil && selectedIndexPaths!.contains(indexPath)
cell.accessoryType = rowIsSelected ? .checkmark : .none
// cell.accessoryView.hidden = !rowIsSelected // if using a custom image
```

Update each cell when it's selected/deselected

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)!
    cell.accessoryType = .checkmark
    // cell.accessoryView.hidden = false // if using a custom image
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)!
    cell.accessoryType = .none
    // cell.accessoryView.hidden = true  // if using a custom image
}
```

When you're done, get an array of all the selected rows

```
let selectedRows = tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows
```

and get the selected data, where `dataArray` maps to the rows of a table view with only 1 section

```
let selectedData = selectedRows?.map { dataArray[$0.row].ID }
```

Comment: I don't understand why this is not the accepted answer... if you use a custom cell you can also change the appearance in you cell's setSelected:animated: method based on the cell's state

Comment: To get selected objects indexs NSArray *selectedCells = [self.tableView indexPathsForSelectedRows];

Answer (score 18):

@BrendanBreg [implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3041086/926907) didn't worked for me. @RaphaelOliveira provided [good solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13827975/926907), but when you scrolls your table down - wrong rows become selected (because `UITableView` caches it's cells). So, I've slightly modified Raphael's solution:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell* cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell* cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
}

/*Here is modified part*/

- (UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    /*
    ...
    Your implementation stays here
    we're just adding few lines to make sure
    that only correct rows will be selected
    */

    if([[tableView indexPathsForSelectedRows] containsObject:indexPath]) {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    } else {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }
}
```

Comment: When scroll it hides the selected rows!

Answer (score 15):

```
self.tableView.allowsMultipleSelection = YES;
```

Answer (score 14):

Just a quick tip in addition to the great answer above: to mimic Apple's style from the clock app (making the row select color fade back out after checking / unchecking the row), add this to the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`, after the conditionals:

```
[self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
```

From Apple's [TableMultiSelect](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/TableMultiSelect/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40011189-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2) guide.

Answer (score 6):

Here it is what you needed
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/TableMultiSelect/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40011189-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2

Answer (score 3):

I have seen this problem with so many developers. Due to table view's nature of re-using cell it removes or haphazard the checks. I have created a working solution for that. Clone/download code from [DevelopmentSupportWorkspace](https://github.com/rptwsthi/DevelopmentSupportWorkspace) and Execute `UITableViewTest` project from there.

Here is code summery for that:

```
@interface CheckBoxTestTableViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *dataArray;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableDictionary *selectedIndexDictionary;

@end

@implementation CheckBoxTestTableViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations.
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;

    //
    _dataArray = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"ImageList" ofType:@"plist"]];
    _selectedIndexDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return _dataArray.count;
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"checkMarkCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

    // Configure the cell...
    cell.textLabel.text = _dataArray[indexPath.row][@"text"];
    if (_selectedIndexDictionary[indexPath] != nil) cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;

    return cell;
}

- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(nonnull NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (_selectedIndexDictionary[indexPath] == nil) {
        [_selectedIndexDictionary setObject:_dataArray[indexPath.row] forKey:indexPath];
        [[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark];
    }else{
        [_selectedIndexDictionary removeObjectForKey:indexPath];
        [[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryNone];
    }
//    [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
}
@end
```

Answer (score 1):

The clock alarms repeat table view is not multiple selection.  Think of it as a lit of checkboxes.

When a cell is selected, the font color and accessory type are changed and the selection fades out.  When a checked cell is selected, the font color and accessory type are changed back and the selection fades out.

In your didSelectRowAtIndexPath delegate method, you would set the text color and accessory type for the selected cell, then deselect the cell.  You would also record the new state in your data model.  That could be as simple as a bit mask representing the selected state, but depends on what data you are displaying.

In your cellForRowAtIndexPath: dataSource method, set the text color and accessory type based on your data model.

Actual multiple selection would be similar.  You have to keep track of which cells are selected, and set the selected cell of each state as it is created or shown.  When the table view reports that a cell is selected, toggle the selection state in your data model and set the selected state of the cell accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You can't key off indexPath because the cells that refers to changes as you scoll.  Put an NSLog in cellForRowAtIndexPath to see that.  You can do the check/uncheck in willSelectRowAtIndexPath or didSelectRowAtIndexPath.  That covers only the initial check or uncheck though, and will also have things appear as checked once you've scrolled because the underlying cell for a given indexPath changes.

So the solution I found is to have an array of selected things with something that is specific to that given cell, and do the initial check.

```
- (NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  UITableViewCell* cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

  if (![selectedIndexes containsObject:cell.textLabel.text]){
    [selectedIndexes addObject:cell.textLabel.text];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
  } else {
    [selectedIndexes removeObject:cell.textLabel.text];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
  }

  return indexPath;
}
```

You also have to have logic in cellForRowAtIndexPath to make sure the right stuff is checked or not as the view scrolls:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

  ...

  cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
  if ([selectedIndexes containsObject:cell.textLabel.text]) {
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    [cell setSelected:YES animated:YES];
  }

  return cell;
}
```

Comment: -1 The indexPath in tableView:didDeselectRowAtIndexPath: does NOT depend on scrolling, and there is no need to keep a separate array of selected items. See @Dmitry solution for a correct implementation

Answer (score 1):

1 - Allow multiple selection and toggle of selected state:

```
tableView.allowsMultipleSelection = true
```

2 - Collect or get an array of all selected indices when you are done:

```
let selected = tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows
```

Note: This is independent of which cells are currently showing on screen.

3 - Change the appearance of the cell depending on selected state: Override this method in your UITableViewCell subclass. If you don't have a subclass, make one.

```
// In UITableViewCell subclass
override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
    accessoryType = selected ? .Checkmark : .None
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is an old posting, but for future use, the following code will solve the problem of ensuring that a checkmark will only appear on selected rows during scrolling:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    cell.accessoryType = (cell.isSelected) ? .checkmark : .none
}
```