# Multiple cell selection In tableview

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I want to upload photos to twitter , facebook and twit pic and many more. I took this in Array and displayed in Table view. I am using shareKit . I coded like if I select one cell (for eg.Twitter) then It will upload photo to twitter I want to select more than one cell and perform this sending action on one button(send to selected row item). I am able to mark/unmark cells but how to get selected value of cell. I dont want it to be in table's editing mode..

Code :

```
-  (void) tableView:(UITableView *)atableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    if (cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark) {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }


    else {

        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    }



}
```

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/308081/is-it-possible-to-configure-a-uitableview-to-allow-multiple-selection and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3040894/uitableview-multiple-selection

Comment: @IphoneDeveloper, if you got the right answer why don't you give an up-vote for the effort?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let `sourceArray` be your array which you use to populate the tableview.
And `selectedObjects` be an array of objects that are selected, initialized to contain 0 objects. It should be a (private) class instance variable.

`//NSMutableArray *selectedObjects = [[NSMutableArray array] retain];`

```
-  (void) tableView:(UITableView *)atableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    YouObjectType *object = [sourceArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; //This assumes that your table has only one section and all cells are populated directly into that section from sourceArray.
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    if (cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark) {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        [selectedObjects removeObject:object];
    }
    else {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
        [selectedObjects addObject:object];
    }
}
```

Then in the sending action method of the button you described, use the objects in the `selectedObjects` array to do the required operation.

Comment: bad idea to use cell with cellforRowAtIndexPath. Good point is saving all your item selection state in an array and check/uncheck it here. Then call reloadData.

Answer (score 1):

You can also make it using check mark  in tableview like..

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)path {
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:path];
 if (cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark) {
cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
} else {
cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can manage it in an array that which cell is selected or which not, when you select a row then in didSelectRowAtIndexPath update that array according to above condition and use that array when you are uploading images. For example - u have an array which have dictionary two objects for key @"image" and @"isSelected" and populate the table with this array and when you select a row then access the element from array as a dictionary object at indexPath.row and update that dictionary "true" or "flase" for key "isSelected".

Comment: Can you refer any example or link?

Answer (score 0):

Get indexPath.row in didSelectRowAtIndexPath, you can know which cell was selected.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this github repo JLSelectionTVC (https://github.com/nvrtdfrst/JLSelectionTVC) which accomplishes this

[image]