# Selecting UITableViewCells with CheckmarkAccessory and cell reuse identifier

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Alright so I'm using a cell reuse identifier to generate `UITableViewCells` on my table view. This `UITableView` displays all of your contacts first and last names, first by grabbing them through `ABAddressBook` and then using the data in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"inviteCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    // forIndexPath:indexPath]; taken from above

    if(tableView == self.tableView)
    {
        //configure the cells for the contacts tableView
        #define CHECK_NULL_STRING(str) ([str isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]] || !str)?@"":str

        id p=[contactsObjects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        NSString *fName=(__bridge NSString *)(ABRecordCopyValue((__bridge ABRecordRef)(p), kABPersonSortByFirstName));
        NSString *lName=(__bridge NSString *)(ABRecordCopyValue((__bridge ABRecordRef)(p), kABPersonSortByLastName));
        cell.textLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",CHECK_NULL_STRING(fName),CHECK_NULL_STRING(lName)];
    }
    else
    {
        //configure the cells for the search bar controller's tableView.

        #define CHECK_NULL_STRING(str) ([str isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]] || !str)?@"":str

        id p=[searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        NSString *fName=(__bridge NSString *)(ABRecordCopyValue((__bridge ABRecordRef)(p), kABPersonSortByFirstName));
        NSString *lName=(__bridge NSString *)(ABRecordCopyValue((__bridge ABRecordRef)(p), kABPersonSortByLastName));
        cell.textLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",CHECK_NULL_STRING(fName),CHECK_NULL_STRING(lName)];

    }

    return cell;

}
```

**What I need to do is**, select any of the cells generated like this, and also be able to deselect any of the cells. In the background, I'll be using the phone numbers associated with each name to check if they're registered in my database. But as for this `UITableView` I need to select any of the table cell's, and **not** also select every 10th cell, or whatever it is.

*Put clearly:* I need to keep track of what cells are checked, and I need to do this using minimal code. I may be wrong, but I believe in my case, I MUST USE cell reuse identifiers, and the cells must me "single-selected" and un-selectable. How do I do this?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/5973945/1824529

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understood correctly.. you need only a single selection on the tableview. Once a new row is selected you deselect the old one.

You can do this like so :

cellForRowAtIndexPath do some thing like this.

```
if(indexPath.row == 0){
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
        self.lastSelected = indexPath;//This will keep track of the last selected cell .
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if([self.lastSelected  compare:indexPath] == NSOrderedSame){
        [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];//This is to remove the highlight on cell selection
        return;
    } else {
        [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
        [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:self.lastSelected].accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        [self setLastSelected:nil];//Releasing the old retain and resetting 
        self.lastSelected = indexPath;
        [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];
    }
}
```

Hope this helps

EDIT :
Ok now i understood your question. my edited answer is given below

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if ([tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark) {
        [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    } else
        [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
}
```

This way you can select multiple cells and deselect any cell which was earlier selected.
The checkmark will be enabled or disabled depending on its earlier state.

Hope i have the correct understanding of what you wish to do.

Comment: Thank you, this does exactly what I wanted except for the cell reuse identifiers. When I select one row it actually selects the corresponding reuse cell down the tableView. But still this works so far as adding and removing the checks