# iOS highlight multiple UITableViewCells

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Is it possible to highlight multiple UITableViewCells?  Something like a filter table.  If the user taps on row 0, it gets highlighted.  Then user taps on row 1 and that also gets highlighted but row 0 stays highlighted also.  I haven't seen any examples for this.

I have a dictionary with 5 items which can get selected, values of which are either yes or no to keep track which ones are highlighted.

I used `(UITableView *)tableView willDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` and set it to `nil` but now I can't unselect rows.  Any help please?

Comment: possible duplicate of [UITableView Multiple Selection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3040894/uitableview-multiple-selection)

Comment: Not a duplicate but there is an answer in that question.  I wasn't asking about adding checkmarks to the cell.  The answer is setting the table to `setAllowsMultipleSelection:`.  I saw that post before but just now noticed that one line down the page.

Comment: You can use that answer as well. Instead of adding checkmarks set the cell as selected or change its background color. Glad you found something that works though.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do to implement this is keep a track of the selected indexes and change the backgroundcolor of table viewCell accordingly, for example:

Declare an Array as SelectedIndexes

Then in your didSelectRowAtIndex method just do this:

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

```
 if([selectedIndex containObject :indexPath]){

       [selectedIndexes removeObject:indexPath];

    }else{

      [selectedIndexes addObject:indexPath];


     }

  [tableView reloadData];
```

}

And then In your CellForRowAtIndexPath Method do this

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
       cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
  {

  if([selectedIndex containObject :indexPath]){

  cell.backgroundColor=highlightedColor;
      }else{

  cell.backgrounfColor=NormalColor;

  ```
  }
  ```

}
Hope this Helps