# Get checkbox on tableview cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I know this question has been asked before, but there is a confusion among those. As i need multiple checkmark on cell and on clicking again on that cell checkmark should be set to none for that selected cell. i have tried this but all cell get selected doesnot none when again clicking on selected cell. i have tried this.

```
- (UITableViewCell )tableView:(UITableView )tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   myTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"myTableViewCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
 cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

    return cell;
}
```

and in  didSelectRowAtIndexPath

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView )tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath   )indexPath
{
     myTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"myTableViewCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    if ( cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryNone) {
         cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    }
   else
   {
       cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
   }

    }
```

and in didDeselectRowAtIndexPath

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView )tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath )indexPath
{
    myTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"myTableViewCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    if ( cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryNone) {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    }
    else
    {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }
}
```

Please help.

Comment: Just remove/comment method `didDeselectRowAtIndexPath` and then try..

Comment: why you are using `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` inside didSelectRowAtIndexPath and  didDeselectRowAtIndexPath methods ... use `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

Comment: that all right there is no need to tuse didDeselect and you need to store selected index in array and you need to check with indexPath.row is same or not in cellforrowIndexPath

Comment: When you select one cel then you go down then you select 2 second cell then you go above then i think check remove automatic right ?

Comment: http://abcode.info/index/show/87289

Comment: as i want keep multiple selection checkmarks and want to remove checkmarks when i select on already checkmarked cell.

Comment: I have created a working solution for your problem download it from here https://github.com/rptwsthi/DevelopmentSupportWorkspace Also you can see details about solution here http://stackoverflow.com/a/36420352/656600

Answer (score 0):

You just need to maintain the state of cell whether is it selected or not.
Try this in your cellForRowAtIndexPath.

```
if ([tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows containsObject:indexPath]) {
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
}
else
{
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
}
```

Comment: it's not working..