# Select multiple item in a tableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

With the help of a tutorial i built this class

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class SelectClass: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, 
UITableViewDataSource  {


    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    var list : [QCategoryy] = [QCategoryy]()
    var audioPlayer : AVAudioPlayer!



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        self.title = "Categories"
        list = NearbyPlaces.getCategories()
    }



    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)


        list.sort() { $0.views > $1.views}
        tableView.reloadData()
    }


    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }




    @IBAction func backTapp(_ sender: Any) {

        let audioUrl = NSURL.fileURL(withPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: 
        "pop_drip", ofType: "m4a")!)
        do{
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
            .setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)

            try audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: audioUrl)
            audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
            audioPlayer.play()
        }
        catch _ as NSError
        {

        }
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

    }


    @IBAction func doneTapp(_ sender: Any) {

        let audioUrl = NSURL.fileURL(withPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: 
        "pop_drip", ofType: "m4a")!)
        do{
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
            .setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)

            try audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: audioUrl)
            audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
            audioPlayer.play()
        }
        catch _ as NSError
        {

        }

}




    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: 
    Int) -> Int {
        return list.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: 
    IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let identifier = "CATEGORY_CELL"
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: identifier, 
        for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = list[indexPath.row].name
        return cell
    }

    let nearbySearchSegueIdentifier = "goToMcourse"
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: 
    IndexPath) {
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: nearbySearchSegueIdentifier, 
        sender: list[indexPath.row])
    }














    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

        if segue.identifier == nearbySearchSegueIdentifier {
            guard let category = sender as? QCategoryy else {
                return
            }
            if let vc = segue.destination as? CourseClass2 {
                vc.category = category
            }
        }
    }
}









extension QCategoryy {
    private static let ketPrefix = "category-"

    var views:Int {
        get {
            return UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: QCategoryy.ketPrefix + name)
        }
    }

    func markView() {
        UserDefaults.standard.set(views + 1, forKey: QCategoryy.ketPrefix + name)
    }
}
```

where it is a tableView with a list of places type (google places) and if i tap one of them i'll go into the controller afterwards where i'll see all the nearby places of that type. But I would like to have the option of selecting more than one line on the tableView and maybe continue after pressing a button like this

```
 @IBAction func doneTapp(_ sender: Any) { 
}
```

how i have to change this class to make this happen?

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3040894/uitableview-multiple-selection.

Comment: (upd) Link by D.Mika is probably even better, has more detailed answer.

Comment: @Hexfire yes so good , but there is a question, now that i have tapped multiple lines how can i use this  self.performSegue(withIdentifier: nearbySearchSegueIdentifier, sender: list[indexPath.row])  in a button func, to go on the next viewController when i finish to select the lines?

Comment: Please be more specific. Where is the button located? Is it in the cell or outside of tableview?

Comment: @Hexfire yes sorry, the button is outside the tableview

Comment: And what is the information you would like to pass along in that action? Do you need indexes of selected rows, corresponding data?

Comment: @Hexfire yes i would like to pass the selected rows , i used this before self.performSegue(withIdentifier: nearbySearchSegueIdentifier, sender: list[indexPath.row])  in the tableView when i didn't need to select multiple items

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's recap.

Here you can find great answer on multiple selection:
[UITableView Multiple Selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3040894/uitableview-multiple-selection)

It starts with:
`tableView.allowsMultipleSelection = true`

and so on.

> now that i have tapped multiple lines how can i use this self.performSegue(withIdentifier: nearbySearchSegueIdentifier, sender: list[indexPath.row]) in a button func,

You don't have to provide `sender` with `performSegue`, it can well accept `nil`. Just specify segue id and nil as a sender and you're all set:

```
@IBAction func doneTapp(_ sender: Any) { 
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: nearbySearchSegueIdentifier, sender: nil)
}
```

However, you should now prepare that segue. If you're concerned with the sender then be sure to check for nullability.

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    if let sender = sender {
        // sender is set...

    } else {
        // Handle preparation when there is no sender.
        // Check if there are selected rows
        if let selectedRows = tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows {

            if let vc = segue.destination as? YourDestination {
                // pass selectedRows to destination controller
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So what you have left is to specify what exactly kind of information you'd like to pass along. Declare public field in that view controller of the required type and pass needed data based on selected indexes, something along the lines of:

```
let selectedData = selectedRows?.map { dataArray[$0.row].ID }
```

Comment: where i have to add let selectedData = selectedRows?.map { dataArray[$0.row].ID } ? and how i declare "dataArray" ?

Comment: `dataArray` is the array that contains data for your tableView. Your tableView is populated with some content, right? There's a data provided into that table, typically an array. So, by calling:  `let selectedData = selectedRows?.map { dataArray[$0.row].ID }` (replace dataArray with your array and `.ID` with any field you need), you are gathering all necessary data you want to pass to a viewcontroller. You set this data into something like vc.selectedItems, where `selectedItems` is the array that you have created in your destination viewcontroller.

Comment: understand, thank you!

Comment: so you need to update your `prepare(for: segue)` method, and before viewcontroller is shown,  call something like `vc.selectedItems = selectedRows` or whatever exactly you need to pass.