# How to store multiple value in single variable in uitableview didselect method

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm new to swift I don't know how to pass the multiplevalues in single value. I can use multiple selection when to passinto the next page.so how to store the mutiple values in singlevalue.any one help me?? my code is

```
var strRoomType = ""  
var strroomtype = []
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
{
    let proModel = arrSpaceData[indexPath.row] as? RoomPropertyModel
    let propertyView = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DepartureLocationVC") as! DepartureLocationVC
    propertyView.strRoomType = (proModel?.property_id as String?)!
  //  propertyView.strroomtype = (proModel?.property_id as String?)!
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(propertyView, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: Why not you just pass the whole  Model "RoomPropertyModel" to DepartureLocationVC ??

Comment: Obviously use array/dictionary .

Comment: it's knowting but to get the name,id,description

Comment: class RoomPropertyModel : NSObject {
    var success_message : NSString = ""
    var status_code : NSString = ""
    var property_name : NSString!
    var property_id : NSString!
    var property_description : NSString!
    func initiatePropertyData(responseDict: NSDictionary) -> Any
    {
        property_name = MakentSupport().checkParamTypes(params: responseDict, keys:"name"); 
        return self
    }}

Comment: So is the idea to be able to select multiple cells in the table and then perform some action to go to the next controller passing the details of those selections?

Comment: yes, I need to pass the select multiple cell values  to pass another viewController

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say that you have two Controllers where one displays a list of students inside a TableView, then the other controller gets pushed and only displays a single student info.

First, you'd need to group all needed info into either a `struct` or `class`, I'll use struct since it's value type. (look up reference vs value type if you don't know it)

```
struct Student {
   let name: String  // using let prevent your fields from being changed or mutated
   let age: Int 
}
```

> Assume that we're into the first Controller that contains the `UITableView`

This would be how you'd go about setting the your tableView:

1) The array that populate the tableView will look like `arr = [Student]()`

2) Say that you are using a default `UITableViewCell`, you'd set the fields like  `cell.textLabel.text = arr[indexPath.row].name`, and `cell.detailTextLabel?.text = String(arr[indexPath.age])`

3) `numberofitemsinsection` would be `arr.count`

**I mean you get the gist...**

```
   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        /* here you have many options 
           on how to pass the **selected data** to the detail controller.
         1) injecting the data into the detail controller via the initializer/ constructor  
         2) via property 
         3) injecting via method such as func setStudent(_ student: Student)
         4) etc...
        */

       let vc = DetailViewController(student: arr[indexPath.row])          
       self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
    }
```

> DetailViewController

```
final class DetailViewController: UIViewController {
   private let student:Student 
   private let nameLabel:UILabel ....

   init(student: Student) { //<--- injecting the student object into the controller 
     self.student = student 
     self.init(nibName: nil , bundle: nil)
   }

  // now you have the student do whatever you want with it 
  override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()
       nameLabel.text = student.name 
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You will have to collect the `indexpaths` of all the selected rows. Get the array `objects/models` of selected `indexpaths` and store them in a single array. Then you can pass that entire array to the next `viewcontroller` or wherever you want to use. If you are going to navigate to next `viewcontroller` on row selection, you will always have one `object/model` and so you won't need an array. You can simply pass entire object/model to the next `viewcontroller`.

Comment: Sorry buddy but I don't have a ready code or demo of it. Give a try or else we will continue in chat. A link for you :: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3040894/uitableview-multiple-selection