# Keep atleast one row selected in UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Hi have a UITableView which has option to check/uncheck each row. It is working properly, no I want to make sure that atleast one row is selected and when user tries to uncheck show him an alert that atleast one option must be selected. How can i implement this?

This is current code

```
private var locationToDisplay = [Location]();
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.tableView.dataSource=self
    self.tableView.delegate=self
    self.tableView.allowsMultipleSelection = true
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return locationToDisplay.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "SubscriptionCell", for: indexPath) as! SubscriptionTableViewCell
    let cellLocation = locationToDisplay[indexPath.row]
    cell.labelLocation.text = cellLocation.location_name

    if cellLocation.subscribed == 1 {
        self.tableView.selectRow(at: indexPath, animated: false, scrollPosition: .none)
    } else {
        self.tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: false)
    }
    return cell
}
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
       locationToDisplay[indexPath.row].subscribed = 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if (countSelections()==1) {
        //Last checked item
    }

       locationToDisplay[indexPath.row].subscribed = 0
}

func countSelections()->Int {
    var count: Int = 0
    for location in locationToDisplay {
        if (location.subscribed == 1) {
            count = count + 1
        }
    }
    return count
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take advantage of the 'UITableViewDelegate' willDeselectRowAt method like this:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> IndexPath? {
    guard tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows?.count ?? 0 == 1 else { return indexPath}

    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "You must keep at least one cell selected", preferredStyle: .alert)
    alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: nil))
    self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

    return nil
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Look into the `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> IndexPath?` delegate method. Here you can return nil if you don't want the user to actually deselect the row (and you can then show an alert as well).

(Also, you should not be calling `self.tableView.selectRow` or `self.tableView.deselectRow` from within the `cellForRowAt` method. Check out https://stackoverflow.com/a/13827975/403425 for more help.)

Answer (score 0):

By your implementation of `didDeselect` the user can check at most one cell.
You can check if that row is selected unselect it: (because didDeselect triggers automatically)

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if (countSelections()==1) {
        //Last checked item
    }
    if (locationToDisplay[indexPath.row].subscribed == 1) {
       locationToDisplay[indexPath.row].subscribed = 0
    }
}
```

Also you can remove this override And handle selecting and unselecting cell in `didSelect`.

And you can check what you want by this way:

first you should check if there is the first item selected or not (declare it in `viewDidLoad`) : `firstTime = true`

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if (!firstTime) {
        if (countSelections() > 1) {
            if (locationToDisplay[indexPath.row].subscribed == 1) {
                locationToDisplay[indexPath.row].subscribed = 0
            } else {
                locationToDisplay[indexPath.row].subscribed = 1
            }
        }
    } else {
      locationToDisplay[indexPath.row].subscribed = 1
      firstTime = false
    }
}
```

Also I think the better way is allow user to unselect all and check the count of selections in a button that makes view transit to another.